# how to take print out of a page in pdf format using php?

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)
>   [Which is the best PDF library for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php)

I am trying to take the print out of a web page in pdf format.

How can this be done?

Comment: Rather similar to your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207293/hwo-to-take-the-print-out-of-a-page-using-php

Comment: Did you perhaps try [searching your question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+take+print+out+of+a+page+in+pdf+format+using+php) first?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a free save to pdf tool
http://www.dopdf.com/

If you then want to share this with othe people on your website then upload the file and link to it via href

```
<a href="file.pdf">download pdf</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php or http://www.fpdf.org/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pdf generator library in your php file

Download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/

See README.txt for installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these:

1. [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)
2. [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
3. [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)